# Microsoft SQL - Bill of material, how to query only lowest parts in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have classic bill of material table:

| PartId | SubPartId | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | 13 |

When given `PartId`, I want only those `SubPartId` that are not Parts (`SubPartId` is not present in `PartId` column), they are materials, so they are lowest in hierarchy. If given `PartId` = 1, I want query to return 3, 5, 8, because those parts don't have any subparts, not sure how to do it.

Tryed simple recursion:

```
with BOM as (
    SELECT  parts.PartId,
            parts.SubPartId
    FROM Parts parts
    WHERE parts.PartId = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  components.PartId,
            components.SubPartId
    FROM Parts components
    JOIN BOM B
        on B.SubPartId = components.SubPartId )
```

From this query I get 2, 3, 5, 8, but I don't want 2 because it is not material.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

Let's have a quick chat about providing demo data.

For a question like this the data and schema you're using is really helpful for us to be able to answer your question. Consider:

```
DECLARE @parts TABLE (PartID INT, SubPartID INT, Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @parts (PartID, SubPartID, Quantity) VALUES
(1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 4),
(1, 5, 8), (2, 8, 13)
```

This produces a table variable describing your table and it's columns, and some sample data to work with.

On to your question!

From what you describe it seems like you want to know what the subparts of a given part are, which are not parts in their own right. Using the example above we could write this:

```
SELECT p.SubPartID
  FROM @parts p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @parts p2
      ON p.SubPartID = p2.PartID
 WHERE p2.PartID IS NULL
```

Which produces the result set:

```
SubPartID
---------
3
5
8
```

What are we doing? We join back to the same table on the SubPartID column with a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Since we don't want the rows where there's a match we can then use the WHERE clause to filter out the non-nulls.

Edit:

Based on the comment, I think you may be looking for a parts list for a given part (If I want a cake, what do I need?)

```
DECLARE @parts TABLE (PartID INT, SubPartID INT, Quantity INT, Name NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @parts (PartID, SubPartID, Quantity, name) VALUES
(1, NULL, 1, 'Bicyle'), (2, 1, 1, 'Wheel'), (5, 2, 1, 'Rim'), (6, 2, 1, 'Tyre'), (7, 5, 1, 'Spoke'),
(8, 6, 1, 'Rubber'), (9, 6, 1, 'Valve'), (10, NULL, 1, 'Cake'), (11, 10, 3, 'Flour'), (12, 10, 1, 'Milk'),
(13, 10, 2, 'Egg'),(14, 13, 1, 'Yoke'), (15, 13, 1, 'White'),(16, 10, 3, 'Sugar'), (17, 10, 1, 'Berries'),
(18, 17, 1, 'Raspberry'),(19, 17, 1, 'Strawberry'), (20, 17, 1, 'Blueberry')
```

Here's some data that's a better fit for this example.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT PartID AS GlobalParentPartID, PartID, SubPartID, Quantity, Name
  FROM @parts
 UNION ALL
SELECT GlobalParentPartID, r.PartID, r.SubPartID, r.Quantity, r.Name
  FROM cte a
    INNER JOIN @parts r
      ON a.PartID = r.SubPartID
)

SELECT i.GlobalParentPartID, i.Name, p.Name, p.SubPartID, p.Quantity
  FROM cte i
    INNER JOIN @parts p
      ON i.GlobalParentPartID = p.PartID
      AND i.PartID <> p.PartID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @parts p2
      ON i.PartID = p2.SubPartID
 WHERE p2.PartID IS NULL
 ORDER BY i.GlobalParentPartID
```

This uses a recursive common table expression to walk through and find all the parts that ultimately roll up to another part.

```
GlobalParentPartID  Name        Name    SubPartID   Quantity
------------------------------------------------------------
1                   Rubber      Bicyle  NULL        1
1                   Valve       Bicyle  NULL        1
1                   Spoke       Bicyle  NULL        1
2                   Rubber      Wheel   1           1
2                   Valve       Wheel   1           1
2                   Spoke       Wheel   1           1
5                   Spoke       Rim     2           1
6                   Rubber      Tyre    2           1
6                   Valve       Tyre    2           1
10                  Flour       Cake    NULL        1
10                  Milk        Cake    NULL        1
10                  Sugar       Cake    NULL        1
10                  Raspberry   Cake    NULL        1
10                  Strawberry  Cake    NULL        1
10                  Blueberry   Cake    NULL        1
10                  Yoke        Cake    NULL        1
10                  White       Cake    NULL        1
13                  Yoke        Egg     10          2
13                  White       Egg     10          2
17                  Raspberry   Berries 10          1
17                  Strawberry  Berries 10          1
17                  Blueberry   Berries 10          1
```

From this we can see that if we want to make an Egg, we need yoke and white. If we want to make a Cake we need Flour, Milk, Sugar, Raspberry
Strawberry, Blueberry, Yoke and White. Flour, Milk and Sugar are ingredients, Egg and Berries are parts with their own ingredients (Yoke and White / Raspberry, Strawberry and Blueberry).

I think this might be what you're trying to get to based on your most recent comment.

Comment: Thank you for gently guiding a new user onto being a productive contributor!

Comment: @PatrickHurst thanks for guidance about providing sample data! I did not understand how would I provide PartID to this query and retreive all its subparts?

Comment: Im not sure what you're meaning by "provide partID"? Are you asking how to apply a variable representing a particular part?

Answer (score 0):

I find using `not exists` is a natural fit here. Using the sample data provided by another answer here:

```sql
select *
from @parts as child
where not exists (
    select PartID
    from @parts as parent
    where parent.PartID = child.SubPartID
);
```

The query, in plain language, says "find rows where they are not the parent of another row". If you want to further reduce the set, you could apply a `group by` or `distinct` to the list of SubPartIDs.

Comment: thanks for answering! Not sure how to provide PartId to this query. Like you said, it will return all rows that are not parent of another row, but I need to provide PartId and go down the hierarchy.

Comment: Ah... I see. Just to clarify, is there a row in your actual data for all of the parts? For example, the only mention I see for PartID = 8 is implied as a subpart of PartID = 2. How I often see these sorts of hierarchies implemented is inverted from what you have. Which is to say you have (PartID, ParentPartID) relationships and top-level entity (say a bicycle) has no parent and the parts needed to make it (say "wheel") roll up to that. Not to say that what you have is incorrect, just that that model has all entities represented in the data.

Comment: @BenHul It is Parent\Child hierarchy, where Parent is ParentId column and Child is SubPartId column. I would have bicycle as PartId and wheel as SubPartId, but then we can also have wheel as a PartId and ruber and steel as SubPartIds. In that case, I don't really need wheel to return, but ruber and steel ( bottom of hierarchy).